# How to change one remote branch into an exact copy of another remote branch?

Tags: git

I have two branches in remote. Release and Master. Both branches have similar code. I want all the code in Release to match the Master branch. That means any additional changes in Release and not in master should be destroyed and any changes in Master and not in Release should be placed into Release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally mean that you want to discard the current Release branch and recreate it so that it exactly mirrors the current Master branch, the command sequence to use (in a clean clone of the repo) is

```
> git checkout -t origin/Release
> git reset --hard master
> git push origin --force Release:Release
```

But there's no way back from this